# Exercise sum equal to 1 using only the digits 1,2, 3,...,9

Tags: contest-math

Give a method to write the number one as the sum of three fractions, where each fraction the numerator is a one-digit number the denominator is a two-digit number and numbers that can be used are from 1 to 9 without repeating numbers.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can actually confirm that the answer that was posted first **is the only solution** since the search space of this problem is relatively small and can be iterated over quickly. There are exactly $$\frac{1}{6} {9\choose 3} {6\choose 3} = 280$$ combinations for the three values  to examine. Each of these then produces $6^3$ different combinations of fractions, as each choice of digit triples can represent six fractions.

We code this in Perl. The output of the following Perl program is $$9/12 + 5/34 + 7/68.$$ This program runs extremely fast since it uses an effective algorithm (lexical ordering of the elements of the combinations being examined) to compute only the relevant $280$ combinations, as opposed to iterating over all $9!$ permutations which given the factor of $6^3$ of actual values for the fractions is not feasible.

This is the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

sub threeperms {
    my @l = @{ $_[0] };

    return
      [[$l[0], $l[1], $l[2]],
       [$l[0], $l[2], $l[1]],
       [$l[1], $l[0], $l[2]],
       [$l[1], $l[2], $l[0]],
       [$l[2], $l[0], $l[1]],
       [$l[2], $l[1], $l[0]]];
}

sub compute {
    my ($r, $a, $b, $c) = @_;

    my $n = scalar(@$r);
    if($n==0){
      print STDERR "@$a @$b @$c\n";

      foreach $ap (@{threeperms($a)}){
          my $av = $ap->[0]/(10*$ap->[1]+$ap->[2]);

          foreach $bp (@{threeperms($b)}){
            my $bv = $bp->[0]/(10*$bp->[1]+$bp->[2]);

            foreach $cp (@{threeperms($c)}){
                my $cv = $cp->[0]/(10*$cp->[1]+$cp->[2]);

                print 
                  "$ap->[0]/$ap->[1]$ap->[2] + " .
                  "$bp->[0]/$bp->[1]$bp->[2] + " .
                  "$cp->[0]/$cp->[1]$cp->[2]\n"

                  if abs(-1+$av+$bv+$cv)<1e-6;
            }
          }
      }

      return;
    }

    for(my $pos=0; $pos<$n; $pos++){
      my $el = splice @$r, $pos, 1;

      if($n>6){
          compute($r, [@$a, $el], $b, $c)
            if (scalar(@$a)==0 || 
                $a->[-1]<$el);
      }
      elsif($n>3){
          compute($r, $a, [@$b, $el], $c)
            if (scalar(@$b)==0 || 
                ($a->[0]<$b->[0] && $b->[-1]<$el));
      }
      else{
          compute($r, $a, $b, [@$c, $el])
            if (scalar(@$c)==0 || 
                ($b->[0]<$c->[0] && $c->[-1]<$el));
      }

      splice @$r, $pos, 0, $el;
    }
}


MAIN: {
    my @digits = (1..9);

    compute(\@digits, [], [], []);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

$$1=\frac{5}{34}+\frac{7}{68}+\frac{9}{12}$$

Comment: It would be nice if you mentioned how can this be arrived at without bruteforce..

Comment: sorry but I could only find this by brute force.  I didn't try to claim more and tried to work backwards to determine a way to get the answer but failed.